# How do I implement Nativescript + Angular list view swipe actions to achieve an item delete?

Tags: ios, angular, listview, mobile, nativescript

I have a RadListView Nativescript + Angular element that I would like to delete items from via swipe action:

```
    <RadListView [items]="stockList" id="listview" style="height: 100%; background-color: #f5f5f5;" swipeActions="true" pullToRefresh="true"
               (pullToRefreshInitiated)="onPullToRefreshInitiated($event)"
               (itemSwipeProgressEnded)="onSwipeCellFinished($event)"
               (itemSwipeProgressStarted)="onSwipeCellStarted($event)"
               (itemSwipeProgressChanged)="onCellSwiping($event)">

    <ng-template let-item="item">
      <GridLayout rows="*,*" colSpan="5" columns="*,2*,*,*" (tap)="onTap(item.name)">
        <SVGImage col="0" row="0" rowSpan="2" class="pgrRating" [src]="pgrRating(item.PGR, item.raw_PGR)"></SVGImage>

        <!-- TICKER -->
        <Label row="0" col="1" horizontalAlignment="left" class="itemName" [text]="item.symbol"></Label>

        <!-- COMPANY NAME -->
        <Label row="1" col="1" horizontalAlignment="left" class="itemCompName" [text]="item.name"></Label>

        <!-- LAST PRICE TODAY -->
        <Label row="0" col="2" colSpan="2" horizontalAlignment="left" class="itemPrice"
               [text]="'$' + (item.Last).toFixed(2)"
               [ngClass]="item.Change == 0 ? 'black' : (item.Change > 0 ? 'green' : 'red')"></Label>

        <Label  style="color: #c00000" row="0" col="3" class="icon" text="&#xf071;"></Label>

        <!-- $ CHANGE TODAY  -->
        <Label row="1" col="2" horizontalAlignment="left" class="itemChange"
               [text]="item.Change.toFixed(2)"
               [ngClass]="item.Change == 0 ? 'black' : (item.Change > 0 ? 'green' : 'red')"></Label>

        <!-- % CHANGE TODAY -->
        <Label row="1" col="3" horizontalAlignment="left" class="itemPriceChange"
               [text]="item.Change > 0 ? ('(+' + item['Percentage '].toFixed(2) + '%)') : ('(' + item['Percentage '].toFixed(2) + '%)')"
               [ngClass]="item.Change == 0 ? 'black' : (item.Change > 0 ? 'green' : 'red')"></Label>
      </GridLayout>
    </ng-template>
</RadListView>
```

Problem is, I'm not sure where to put the swipe template to retain the 'let-item ngFor' behavior to get the index of that item. The docs mention to put the template:

```
<GridLayout *tkListItemSwipeTemplate columns="auto, *, auto" class="gridLayoutLayout">
  <StackLayout id="mark-view" col="0" class="icon" (tap)="onLeftSwipeClick($event)">
    <Label text="mark" class="swipetemplateLabel" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center"></Label>
  </StackLayout>
  <StackLayout id="delete-view" col="2" class="" (tap)="onRightSwipeClick(item.index)">
    <Label row="0" col="2" text="&#xf1f8;" class="icon swipeIcon" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center"></Label>
  </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

under the `<ng-template>` but if I do so, I lose out on the 'item' loop and then don't know how to pass the index. If I place the swipe template inside the ng-template to retain the item index, then the list displays a blank area where the template would be, so then my list can't occupy the whole height of the view.

Any advice? Thanks so much!!

Comment: If you need a working example, take a look at https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-pluginshowcase/blob/8ccc2a201617257c4ff69bfa064a1195d8472925/app/firebase/firebase.component.html#L35-L62 - you can install the app from the app store as well to give it a go (see the readme in the repo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put SwipeTemplate in a GridLayout outside of the ng-template in order to achieve Swipe actions like delete et cetera. Everything you need to get an index is sent through args. Check out the example provided, I hope it helps.

```
// xml file
<GridLayout orientation="vertical" rows="auto, *" tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton>
    <RadListView #myListView [items]="dataItems" row="1" selectionBehavior="None" (itemSwipeProgressEnded)="onSwipeCellFinished($event)"
        (itemSwipeProgressStarted)="onSwipeCellStarted($event)" (itemSwipeProgressChanged)="onCellSwiping($event)" swipeActions="true">
        <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
            <StackLayout class="listItemStackLayout" orientation="vertical">
                <Label class="labelName" [text]="item.name"></Label>
                <Label class="labelTitle" [text]="item.title"></Label>
                <Label class="labelText" [text]="item.text"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </ng-template>
        <GridLayout *tkListItemSwipeTemplate columns="auto, *, auto" class="gridLayoutLayout">
            <StackLayout id="mark-view" col="0" class="markViewStackLayout" (tap)="onLeftSwipeClick($event)">
                <Label text="mark" class="swipetemplateLabel" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout id="delete-view" col="2" class="deleteViewStackLayout" (tap)="onRightSwipeClick($event)">
                <Label text="delete" class="swipetemplateLabel" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </GridLayout>
    </RadListView>
</GridLayout>


// typescript file
public onLeftSwipeClick(args: ListViewEventData) {
    console.log("Left swipe click");
    this.listViewComponent.listView.notifySwipeToExecuteFinished();
}

public onRightSwipeClick(args) {
    console.log("Right swipe click");
    this.dataItems.splice(this.dataItems.indexOf(args.object.bindingContext), 1);
}
```